# Which is the best way to return more than one strings in the same method in C#

Tags: c#, methods

Following is an example of the method.Because this method is used in several components, I cannot change the string type as array. All I'm trying to do is to return two strings. Is this possible?

```
protected override string getSourceName()
{
    return "ConditionalSymbology.InsertSymbologyRuleData";
}
```

Comment: serialize it somehow

Comment: Is it exactly 2 or it might be more?

Comment: exact 2 .. not more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the main problem, that you should solve (because now you are trying to solve [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) is bad object design. You have the method that returns one `string` in some scenarios and collection of strings in others.

You should redesign your classes to have necessary return values in different scenarios. If your current class have common code you can encapsulate it in protected methods.

If your current architecture used in external components you can using versioning without backward compatibility for use old library in existing code and new one for new components.

It's very general issue but you can try to ask this question in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yes.. I thought so too. It is complicated, so I was looking for an easy way out. But thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to return two strings without changing the function. You can return one string that the caller will attempt to interpret by splitting it according to commas or whatever, like `value1,value2` or `value1:value2`.

But it will always be one string. If another method calls this function, it will need to know that it must split that one string into multiple strings, and what each part of that string means.

So the short answer is that there is no way for the function to return two strings unless you change what it returns.

That raises a big question: You said you can't change it because it's already called by other methods. If you can't change those methods, then what would happen if you changed the values returned to those methods? They used to get one string, but now they get a string with multiple values.

So all you can do is write the function that you need, and have it return what it needs to return. Maybe your existing code can keep calling the old function and the new code can call the new function.

Comment: Yes, I guess that thats the only option I have. Was looking for a simpler way to sort this .. thanks a lot!